# How to get the Split value from collection?

Tags: c#, strings, array, linq

I have the following key value pair in an array, and am trying to extract and load them into a collection.

The below code is working but it can be optimized using Linq:

```
string _data = "Website=url:www.site1.com,isdefault:true,url:www.site2.com,isdefault:true";

List<WebSiteAddress> _websiteList = new List<WebSiteAddress>() ;
WebSiteAddress _website = new WebSiteAddress();

string[] _websiteData = _divider[1].Split('=');
string[] _WebsiteKeyValuePair = _websiteData[1].Split(',');

for (int j = 0; j < _WebsiteKeyValuePair.Length; j++)
{
    string key = _WebsiteKeyValuePair[j].Split(':')[0];
    string value = _WebsiteKeyValuePair[j].Split(':')[1];

    if (key.ToLower() == "url")
    {
        _initWebsite.Url = value;
    }
    else if (key.ToLower() == "isdefault")
    {
        _website.IsDefault = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        _websiteList.Add(_website);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: There's some discussion about where this belongs. Someone (not the OP) migrated/copied it here from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100017/how-to-get-the-split-value-from-collection). It's got at least one answer on SO.

Comment: What's `_divider`?

Comment: You are never using `_data`, and you did not provide a sample of `_divider[1]`. Please review and update your question.

Comment: Instead of performing the same split operation twice to get the key and value you should split once and store the result in a temporary variable first. You should also do the `ToLower()` operation when you assign the value to `key`. That way you don't have to do a `ToLower()` in each `if` statement.

Answer (score 5):

#### Naming

I don't get the `_` underscore prefix. This typically identifies a *private field* (albeit controversial). I'm pretty sure there's a consensus about simple `camelCasing` for local identifiers.

The name `_websiteList` is a bad one, for two reasons:

- It's of type `WebSiteAddress`, which has words `Web` and `Site`; the name isn't following the established casing convention, should be `_webSiteList`.
- It's tying the variable to its type. Would the name still make sense if the type was `WebSiteAddress[]`?

A better name would be, simply, `webSiteAddresses`.

#### Typing

If you want to use LINQ, you're targeting .NET 3.5+. Therefore, you can use implicit typing to improve the readability (and possibly the maintainability) of your code (although that's possibly personal preference).

Consider:

- `var webSiteData = _divider[1].Split('=');`

---

The SO answer gives you a nice *LINQ-oriented* approach.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestions:

- Use a foreach instead of a for;
- Don't redo operations such as `_WebsiteKeyValuePair[j].Split(':')` and `key.ToLower()`, store them in a variable instead;
- Use a switch instead of an if-chain.

Switch would look like:

```
switch(key.ToLower())
{
    case "url":
        _initWebsite.Url = value;
        break;
    case "isdefault":
        ...
        break;
}
```

As for LINQ, you have an answer in the Stackoverflow cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100355/148412